# IIS 7.5 application pool CPU configuration

Tags: iis-7, memory-usage, multi-core

I have a web application that when runs on windows 2008 r2 data center edition and when the server is configured with a single core processor consumes 13 mb ram, when configured to run on dual core cpu it consumes approximately 25 to 28 mb ram and when configured to use 3 cpu's it consumes approximately 40mb ram.

I have tried to verify this on a quad core system and have adjusted the processor affinity configuration of the application pool and it seems to be the case.

Can anybody verify this or explain how the number of cores has an effect on the amount of memory (private bytes) that am application pool consumes

Answer (score 0):

.Net application? If so, .net allocates one heap per processor.